# How to download Ubuntu 20.04 in a bash script, and store the ISO file on a USB memory stick. Also, it must act as a bootable DVD

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, scripts, live-usb, iso

I want to download Ubuntu by execute the script. I need to create a script, and download Ubuntu ISO to my computer and put it on a USB memory stick, and make it act as a bootable DVD.

Comment: You can `wget` to download the ISO, and then use `dd` (or whatever you prefer on your *unstated* OS) to write the ISO to bootable media so two commands only need be used. But that doesn't allow for verification (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)  I don't see the point in your question  (verification can vary on *unstated* OS, as well as ejecting media etc)

Comment: The best tool varies on your needs, I have two `wget` for daily ISOs (one for iso.zsync & another for the *manifest*), then I `zsync` to get ISO saving bandwidth). I don't have my script write it to thumb-drive (I consider that dangerous; I prefer to ensure I've got a correct thumb-drive mounted) thus my `dd` was replaced by `dus` meaning I get prompted to confirm etc). The actual commands can vary on your needs (ie. `wget` + `zsync` saves me bandwidth over `wget` alone)   *I'm running my script sometimes multiple times per day for 'daily' images*

Comment: Why can you not just download the Ubuntu ISO from the Ubuntu site and install it on USB using mkusb, Etcher or Rufus? That will make a Live or Persistent USB.

Comment: Dear @guiverc, I can download the ios with wget, but after that i want to burn the image file into a DVD, and i want to write down the code on a script .

Comment: `dd` in my first comment will write to whatever media is mentioned in the command, be it hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/dvd/cd/etc.  I used to use `dd` until I erased a 2tb hdd accidently (I didn't learn), then overwrote an 11TB disk array...  finally switching me to `dus` (which is part of `mkusb` also mentioned by @C.S.Cameron)  *Be careful how much you automate tasks.. it can be dangerous*

Comment: I prefer `aria2c` and `cat` instead of `wget` and `dd` but that's just personal preference (although, I think they're both faster anyhow). However, this would be difficult to do safely as the disk `/dev/sd*` changes. If you run it on the wrong disk, you destroy your data. You'd have to get really fancy with the script and provide input options for the disk.

Comment: There's a reason they call `dd` "disk destroyer".